# Sine wave generator using a triangle wave input

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator

I'm covering oscillators in my class right now and in the foot notes of my professor's notes he says that there is a "dirty and cheap" trick to generating sine waves. I replicated the circuit below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT3OAp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't have any more detail about this and I'm failing to see how this would generate a sine wave. From the looks of it, it looks like a series of tangential approximations but I would appreciate more clarity.

Comment: Two levels of soft clipping approximate a sine wave. It is a mediocre approximation.

Comment: The sine wave slopes extend to 1.3* Vp to make a triangle so this is the amount of soft compression needed on a triangle loading to the linear slope between 1/3 and 2/3. It can be improved.

Comment: It also works best (still not really well) at one specific input amplitude.